# Angular: Bind text input value to substring inside textarea

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a textarea, inside which are some substrings that match pattern. Is there a way I can edit that substring through text input.

**Example**:
I have a textArea that contains next string:

```
${1:scan1}
${2:scan2}
${3:scan3}
```

I am subscribing to valueChanges of it and calling regex to get all repetitions of that string and converting them to FormControl, than pushing it to FormArray, so value pushed through FormControl is only text inside ( ${scan1} -> scan1 )

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" [formControl]="textArea"></textarea>
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  textArea: FormControl = new FormControl("");
  detectedStrings: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.textArea.valueChanges.subscribe((textBodyText: string) => {
      const foundStrings =
        textBodyText.match(/[$][{][1-9][0-9]*[:][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,}[}]/g) || [];
      this.detectedStrings.clear();
      foundStrings.map(_string => {
        this.detectedStrings.push(
          new FormControl(
            _string.substring(_string.indexOf(":") + 1, _string.indexOf("}"))
          )
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Then I'm displaying all found scans in list as input:

```html
<div [formGroup]="detectedStrings">
  <div *ngFor="let string of detectedStrings.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is that as I would edit text in input, text in textarea would also change dynamically. ( scan1 -> scan100 )

**Note**: This is just a recreation

Comment: So as the input changes, the textarea should get updated ? correct?

Comment: Yes correct. Little trick here is if there are two identical substrings, only one you are editing is being changed. So if there are two ${1:scan1}, only the edited one should change.

Comment: Is it the result? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akvdne

Comment: Yes this works almost just as I wanted, thanks. It doesn't work only if there are two same texts (2 comments higher).

Comment: Shloud i post the ans to explain this? Or u need different approach?

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem completly, but I will mark it as answer if you explain it. For the 2 same substrings problem, I was thinking about getting index of string where it starts and ends, then editing it with that information somehow, just don't know how to do that.

Comment: I got it working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9ycud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed following steps,

1. Find all matched tags with their respective indices.
2. Create control inputs.
3. After `keyup` event, get the respective start index of tag from step 1
4. Replace latest value from `FormArray` control to existing value of `TextArea`
5. Update `TextArea`.

Demo  [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9ycud)

**Typescript**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  textArea: FormControl = new FormControl("");

  formArray: FormArray;

  tags: any;

  // array to hold prev changes, which is used to avoid stack size exceeded error
  // as this is cyclic behaviour
  formArrayChanges: string[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.formArray = new FormArray([]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.textArea.valueChanges.subscribe((textBodyText: string) => {
      const regex = /[$][{][1-9][0-9]*[:][a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,}[}]/g;
      const foundStrings = textBodyText.match(regex) || [];

      this.tags = new Object();
      let match;

      while ((match = regex.exec(textBodyText)) != null) {
        this.tags[match.index] = match[0];
      }
      // clear saved array
      this.formArray.clear();

      foundStrings.map(str => {
        // get id and value of control
        let id = str.substring(2, str.indexOf(":"));
        let value = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1, str.indexOf("}"));

        this.formArray.push(new FormControl(value));
      });
    });

    this.textArea.setValue("${1:scan1}\n${1:scan1}\n${2:scan2}\n${3:scan3}");
  }

  onControlKey(index: number) {

    let currTextAreaValue = this.textArea.value;

    const tagStartIndex = Object.keys(this.tags)[index];
    console.log(tagStartIndex, this.tags[tagStartIndex]);

    const valueStartIndex = currTextAreaValue.indexOf(":", tagStartIndex) + 1; // +1 to remove :
    let valueEndIndex = currTextAreaValue.indexOf("}", valueStartIndex);

    currTextAreaValue =
          currTextAreaValue.substring(0, valueStartIndex) +
          this.formArray.at(index).value +
          currTextAreaValue.substring(valueEndIndex);

    this.textArea.setValue(currTextAreaValue);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" [formControl]="textArea"></textarea>

<hr>

<div [formGroup]="formArray">
  <div *ngFor="let string of formArray.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" (keyup)="onControlKey(i)"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my code helps to you.

Step 1. Add event(keyup) to your template.

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" [formControl]="textArea"></textarea>
<div [formGroup]="detectedStrings">
    <div *ngFor="let string of detectedStrings.controls; let i = index">
        <input #box type="text" [formControlName]="i" (keyup)="onKey($event, i)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Step 2. Handle event and update textarea.

```js
onKey(event: any, index: any) { 
    console.log(index + '  changed: ' + event.target.value);    
    this.textArea.setValue('${1:scan1}\n${2:scan2}\n${3:scan33}'); //This is one of sample.
}
```

I think it is hard part to update original text at `textArea`.
But you may know what is requirement, so you can make.

Here is my [sample code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqbkcb)

Comment: It doesn't, since you are setting fixed string.

Comment: @Plochie, Thanks, I didn't know that how to add coding format.